# Internal Server Error (HTTP 500) when issuing an authentication token for OpenStack's demo user

Tags: 14.04, server, openstack, authentication

Trying to install OpenStack on a VM (host Win10, guest UbuntuServer14.04.3) I'm following the installation guide (http://docs.openstack.org/liberty/install-guide-ubuntu). When trying to issue the authentication token for the `demo` user (stage 4 at http://docs.openstack.org/liberty/install-guide-ubuntu/keystone-verify.html) I get the following error:

`Discovering versions from the identity service failed when creating the password plugin. Attempting to determine version from URL.
Internal Server Error (HTTP 500)`

I came across some cases in which other have mentioned relations to the `keystone.log` file (e.g. problem 3 here: https://www.redhat.com/archives/rdo-list/2015-April/msg00041.html) or environment variables (e.g. https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/87237/openstack-an-unexpected-error-prevented-the-server-from-fulfilling-your-request-http-500/) but the only files found in my VM's `/var/log/keystone/` directory are `keystone-manage.log`, `keystone-wsgi-admin.log`, and `keystone-wsgi-public.log`, and using `export` command to set various environment variables didn't help.

Also - I used `netstat` to check open ports, and ports 5000 and 35357 are being listened-to by the VM, though they're listed under `tcp6`. Not sure what that means - I thought I set it all to use IPv4.

Can't seem to go pass this error, and if I understand correctly - it affects my ability to send user requests to port 5000, so OpenStack user nodes (compute, storage, etc.) won't communicate.

Thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the Apache2 server PATH (saved in **tmp**), as referenced in: https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/8307/lockfailed-failed-to-create-usrshareopenstack-dashboardopenstack_dashboardlocalb-api01dummy-1-3096/ and https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/13952/horizon-apache-launch-error/

to solve this, I changed the `LOCAL_PATH` value in `local_settings.py` (installing Liberty on Ubuntu Server 14.04, I found it in `/etc/openstack-dashboard/`)

so I changed `LOCAL_PATH = os.path.dirnames(os.path.abspath(__file__))` to `LOCAL_PATH = '/tmp'`

and now all works fine.

Comment: Yeah sure - thanks for the reminder @Sneetsher